How do I create a custom post type archive page in WordPress without using plugins?
I want to create a custom post type called Books in my WordPress theme and display its archive page without relying on third-party plugins. I registered the custom post type in my theme's functions.php file, and it appears in the WordPress admin area. However, I cannot figure out how to create and customize the archive page for this post type.
Here’s the code I used to register the custom post type:
    register_post_type('books', [
        'labels' => [
            'name' => 'Books',
            'singular_name' => 'Book',
        ],
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => ['slug' => 'books'],
    ]);
}
add_action('init', 'create_custom_post_type');

The custom post type is registered successfully, but when I visit http://example.com/books, I see a default "Page Not Found" error.
What did you try and what were you expecting?
I expected the books archive page to display a list of all my custom posts. I tried:
Resaving the permalink structure in the WordPress settings.
Creating a template file called archive-books.php in my theme folder with basic content:
get_header();
echo "<h1>Books Archive</h1>";
get_footer();

Ensuring that the custom post type is set to public and has_archive is true.
Despite these efforts, the archive page still doesn’t display the custom posts. What am I missing?

"Despite these efforts, the archive page still doesn’t display the custom posts." - are you still getting a 404 now, or is it showing the h1 headline from your archive-books.php?

still getting a 404 now

Any difference, when you request /books/ with a trailing slash? What does get_post_type_archive_link('books') get you?

WordPress may redirect URLs with or without a trailing slash based on permalink settings. If /books/ works but /books doesn't (or vice versa), it might be a permalink structure issue. Ensure consistency by checking Settings > Permalinks and saving them again.This function returns the correct URL for the Books archive page. Use it to verify the URL generated matches what you’re visiting. For example:echo get_post_type_archive_link('books');

Can't tell if you are quoting some generic explanation there now, or if you are talking about results of specific debugging attempts.

I recreated the same setup as you but in my case, using the same code, my links are working fine. Can you give more information about the placement of the code (is it in functions.php) and the enabled plugins? I suggest trying another slug to ensure that there is no conflict with any of the enabled plugins. For example, you can modify the slug from books to custom_theme_books or any other prefix of your preference.

Do you possibly have a page called books that has the same slug? Or an image? This may be why WP is giving you a 404. Since you did say you saved the permalinks and archive-books.php would give you exactly what you're looking for.
